# "Notify when profile form is submitted" not working

Tags: profile, email, groups

I'm a beginner. I created some simple profiles to collect volunteer interests from new contacts. I specified a Group Name for "Add contacts to a group?" and specified a valid email address for "Notify when profile form is submitted?" (I enabled "Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field".)  Everything was working fine for a few months but I'm no longer getting notifications that the new Contacts are being added to the groups.  The contacts are still being added to the appropriate group. I'm just not getting the notifications. There has been no change to the email address.
I think I must have accidentally disabled something.  Any suggestions on how to get the notifications working again?
--mike  (CiviCRM 5.38.0 on WordPress 5.8.2)

Comment: Continuing my troubleshooting, I find that other messages (eg receipts) sent from within CiviCRM to the problematic email address are not being received. But CiviCRM reports them as being sent. Messages sent from within CiviCRM to other email addresses are being received. Emails sent from my regular email account to the problematic email address are received properly.  Could CiviCRM be packaging the messages to this problematic email address is some way that my mail server is rejecting them?

Comment: what about sending an email via Actions on that Contact's summary page. does that work? also the Transactional Mail extension can sometimes help as it creates an Activity (in theory) for every email sent so you have some evidence in civi that it tried.

Comment: Following up, I sent an email from that Contact's summary page via an Action. The result is the same. CiviCRM records the message as Completed in the Contacts Activity summary but the message doesn't arrive at the valid email address (and I've checked the Spam folder.)  I'm guessing that this is not a problem internal to CiviCRM but has something to do with the way the mail server for the valid email address sees messages addresses to that address that are coming from Civi.

Comment: do you have SPF/DKIM set up. Have you checked the mail.log on the server. (are you even sending 'from' the server or some other service?

Comment: Thank you. I will ask our technical wizard to look into this avenue - I don't know how to do it myself. I realize now that the problem is probably not CiviCRM related - it's downstream.

Answer (score 3):

I realize now that the problem is not CiviCRM related - it's downstream and something to do with the email service. I'm sorry to have taken up space on the board here.

Comment: don't consider it wasted space. mail issues can be complex. good on you for putting up an Answer.